# How to retrieve Google+ oAuth2 profile thumbnail picture

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, google-plus

After a long learning curve, I managed to successfully get the user's profile information using the Google API client libraries.

Along with a name and email address, when the user logs in to my web app, I can get their profile picture.

Trouble is, the picture is pretty big, in dimension and bytes. The url for such a picture looks something like this:

```
https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-rdhxDPbmVhg/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAJQ/6Dsr5psyQPs/photo.jpg
```

(Yes, that is me at Coral Castle).

Is there a way to get a thumbnail or icon-sized profile pic, like the kind I see next to the author in the results of a Google search? I notice these aren't a URL, but a data object, so I will probably have to do something in php to render it as an image?

An example of the image info on an author, in the results list of a Google search, looks something like this:

```
data:image/jpeg;base64,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
```

I welcome help in getting me to clarify the question, if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just pass a parameter for size to the URL `?sz=200`

It will become something like `https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/--sahsjak8sjdbs5kNk/AAAAdshjgdshdgAAI/AAAAsdhsHY/knQ6LGqP1Yk/photo.jpg?sz=200`

And you are good to go!

Answer (score 7):

You can adjust the size of the image by appending a `?sz=(size in pixels)` parameter to the URL you got.

Example

```
https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-rdhxDPbmVhg/
AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAJQ/6Dsr5psyQPs/photo.jpg?sz=50
```

Will display as 
[image: Example Profile picture]

What method are you using to retrieve the user information?

The [people.get method of the Google+ API](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people/get) called with `userId=me` for the authenticated User will already return a URL with a `?sz=50` parameter added in the `image.url` field of the response.

Comment: You are full of awesomeness! Works great. I'm using the Google_Client.php and Google_Oauth2Service.php' libraries:
$oauth2 = new Google_Oauth2Service($client);

Comment: Hello, Can you please help me to know How to fetch the profile pic of other users using the url mention in anser
Means I need to store the profile pic url in the database.